# How to get data values from sheet. In this week comparison in excel. Using Vlook or?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

2 cells with `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+1`  and `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+7`. One for this week first day and the other one for the last day of the week. How to get data from this week. Am I going to use VLOOKUP? or something formula. Thanks

I am trying return data that matches these dates. For example on the other sheet i do have date 5/29/2018,5/27/2018 ,4/27/2018 and has data values , and on the other sheet i created summary for data where this week from the first day of the week today to last day of the week today 5/27/2018- 6/2/2018 where those data will be the output the data of 5/29/2018,5/27/2018

These are the dates that i will get from 5/27/2018 - 6/2/2018
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhpx6.png)
FROM THE DATA HERE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QWci.png)

I will get the PRF Control # from the dates that will pass through 5/27/2018- 6/2/2018

Comment: You might need to show some data and expected results to go with this. Are you trying to return data that matches these dates from somewhere? Or are between these dates from somewhere? From where? To where?

Comment: Yes i am trying  return data that matches these dates. For example on the other sheet i do have date 5/29/2018,5/27/2018 ,4/27/2018 and has data values , and on the other sheet i created summary for data where  this week from the first day of the week today to last day of the week today 5/27/2018- 6/2/2018 where those data will be the output  the data of 5/29/2018,5/27/2018

Comment: Please [edit] additional info into the question. It actually hurts my eyes trying to read that in the comments. It will make it easier for others to find. Worth clarifying match exactly those dates or in between and including those dates.

Comment: I already edited the additional info. Please help :/

Comment: Can you please show some data (so we understand the layout) and confirm if you are matching on those dates or between (inclusive/exclusive) those dates

Comment: I already add information please check. the data's from the picture @QHarr thanks!

Comment: Hello sir? @QHarr

Comment: Hi! Please include a data sample so I can see if you are matching dates between week start and week end including weekstart date and weekend date or if just on those two dates.

Comment: I already updated the topic sir. there's a link of the picture can be seen on top. Thanks @QHarr . Please help me. I needed for my weekly report :(

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://ufile.io/kzjx4

Comment: Thank you broo!! I'll message you if i need help in other excel functions. Thanks @QHarr . Sorry, I am amateur at using Excel. Im a C# and Android Developer, im helping my friend in excel thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may be after an index match.

This is the formula in the summary sheet cell B4 and then dragged down for 7 rows to cover selected week:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A4,Sheet1!$C:$C,0)),"")
```

Summary sheet has the two cells (B2 and C2) which determine the week dates to match on or between.

Summary sheet

[image: Summmary sheet]

The data sheet (sheet1) which is referenced by the formulas:

[image: Sheet1]

The formula attempts to match the dates in summary sheet, with Match function, and uses the position number returned as the row number to Index, which then pulls the PRF Control # in the same row.

Comment: Good day! What if sir 2 or more  prf control number in one day? This answer can output one  prf control number.

Comment: Then you best bet is VBA although there are lots of questions on SO about getting all  matches